# netconsole or serial logging in XenServer DomU

Tags: linux, logging, xen, xenserver, linux-kernel

I have some problems with stability of Debian guests in my XenServer hosts.

To debug this problem I wanted to use `netconsole` kernel module, unfortunately, because the Ethernet controller is emulated, it doesn't support polling and in effect netconsole:

```
[23463.961946] netconsole: local port 6665
[23463.961950] netconsole: local IP 10.10.12.10
[23463.961952] netconsole: interface eth0
[23463.961954] netconsole: remote port 6667
[23463.961956] netconsole: remote IP 10.10.12.1
[23463.961958] netconsole: remote ethernet address ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[23463.961962] netconsole: eth0 doesn't support polling, aborting.
[23463.961971] netconsole: cleaning up
```

Are there any alternatives to `netconsole` not requiring physical access to host? I've got network syslog already configured.

#### Edit:

How is it possible to log all serial output coming from a particular DomU?

Comment: What happens to your guests?

Comment: Disk access hangs with `INFO: task jbd2:288 blocked for more than 120 seconds.`

Comment: jbd2 is a daemon for syncing the journal block device in ext4. A workaround might be using ext3.

Comment: The problem is not limited to `jbd2`, sometimes it's `smbd`, sometimes `slapd`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of stretch, but just got this idea while on my way home and typing this with my iPhone. Yes, I have no life and I must scream. Anyway...

I wonder if **pam_tty_audit** module could be used for this. Configure a special user for it, make the user automatically login to some tty, gather the reports about screen events afterwards with **aureport**.

A desperate attempt, I know, but man gotta try.

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not know what the heck jbd2 is I googled and found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/linux/+bug/666828) bug (#666828) in the Ubuntu bug database. I was not able to access the associated RedHat bug but this looks like a serious problem that even hits physical machines.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to run a different domU intended only for serial console to all your other domUs. Then, you can make use of the screen utility to switch from one serial console to a particular domU to another.

Comment: By the way, it is assumed that all domUs are on the same dom0. You also use `minicom` to serial console to the other domUs.